required attribute is unknown for ValidateConfig?
Using the terraform plugin framework.  I have this (simplified) resource schema:
type Thing struct{}

func (t *Thing) Schema(_ context.Context, _ resource.SchemaRequest, resp *resource.SchemaResponse) {
    resp.Schema = schema.Schema{
        Attributes: map[string]schema.Attribute{
            "organization_id": schema.StringAttribute{
                Required: true,
                PlanModifiers: []planmodifier.String{
                    stringplanmodifier.RequiresReplace(),
                },
            },
            "cluster_id": schema.StringAttribute{
                Required: true,
                PlanModifiers: []planmodifier.String{
                    stringplanmodifier.RequiresReplace(),
                },
            },
        },
    }

I've implemented resource.ResourceWithValidateConfig.  Here is ValidateConfig.  Please note I'm just showing the debug code.  I really do need to validate multiple attributes on the resource.
func (t *Thing) ValidateConfig(
    ctx context.Context, req resource.ValidateConfigRequest, resp *resource.ValidateConfigResponse,
) {
    fmt.Println("###DEBUG### ValidateConfig")
    var config ThingModel
    resp.Diagnostics.Append(req.Config.Get(ctx, &config)...)
    if resp.Diagnostics.HasError() {
        return
    }

    if config.OrganizationId.IsUnknown() {
        fmt.Println("###DEBUG### config.OrganizationId is unknown")
    }

When I run terraform plan I see this output:
TF_LOG=WARN terraform plan
╷
│ Warning: Provider development overrides are in effect
│
│ The following provider development overrides are set in the CLI configuration:
│  - repo/repo in ~/bin
│
│ The behavior may therefore not match any released version of the provider and applying changes may cause the state to become incompatible with published releases.
╵
2024-09-25T11:36:49.401-0700 [WARN]  unexpected data: registry.terraform.io/blah/provider:stdout="###DEBUG### ValidateConfig"
2024-09-25T11:36:49.402-0700 [WARN]  unexpected data: registry.terraform.io/blah/provider:stdout="###DEBUG### config.OrganizationId is unknown"

In my terraform script I do have organization_id configured (otherwise I would get Missing required argument error).
Why is config.OrganizationId unknown ?

ValidateConfig is (I believe) supposed to be an interface implementation for the pointer to the struct for the resource, and so I would expect the signature to be more like func (t *Thing) ValidateConfig given the information in the question. Is that accurate?

That's fair.  Updated the description for clarity.
